# Wrong nbf time when decoding JWT token in nestjs

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs, nestjs-jwt

in my app.module I Register JWT as :

```
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`,
      signOptions: {
      expiresIn: "24h" ,
      notBefore:  Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) ,
      
    },
```

but when i decode the token I get these timestamps:

```
 iat: 1699944419,
 nbf: 3399888838,
 exp: 1700030819
```

nbf times shows a wrong datetime ( Sunday, September 26, 2077 5:03:58 PM )

Comment: Looks like it's getting doubled somewhere.

Comment: @ybl hmm. you're right i guess. but where is it doubled and how can i change that? because the only place i edit nbf is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsonwebtoken's `notBefore` field](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback) seems to be time relative to the current time. If you pass a numeric value (which you do), that value will be treated as seconds, which is why you're doubling the time at the moment. [You can see here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/sign.js) that the `nbf` gets assigned [the current timestamp *plus* the `notBefore` option](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/lib/timespan.js), which leads to the doubled time. Give a time *relative* to the current for what you want the `notBefore` to be, instead of an absolute time.